# Controlar si existe una imagen en el servidor

Tags: angular

Estoy intentando filtrar y solo exponer los divs que tengan un background img en esa ruta. Lo he intentado controlar con *ngIf y usando condicionales con ngStyle pero no consigo terminarlo.

```
<div class="columna" [routerLink]="['/product/filtered']" [state]="{ id: famili.id}"
       class="card-1 img-fluid img-thumbnail shadow-sm p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded"
       [ngStyle]="{'background': ' url(../../../assets/' + famili.name + '.jpg) no-repeat 0 0','background-size': '100% 100%'}">
   <div class="card-body-1 h4">
        {{famili.name | uppercase | translate }}
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Si el imagen o archiva tienes en tu carpeta assets, usa los metodos para File

Answer (score 3):

Sería mejor que la API que consumes te devolviera una propiedad booleana que indicara si la familia tiene imagen asignada o no pero aun así te dejo una solución en angular.

En tu `component.ts` puedes hacer una llamada `GET` que haga a una petición al fichero de imagen si este existe en el servidor pues te devolverá la imagen(seguramente en bytes) o un error. Y en función de eso puedes mostrar u ocultar el `div`.

```
fileExists = false;

checkFileExistence(filename: string) {
    // esto lo puedes añadir en un servicio
    // También puedes usar los observables eso depende de como trabajes en tu proyecto
    this.httpClient.get(`https://miserver.com/assets/${filename}.jpg`).toPromise()
    .then(response => this.fileExists = true)
    .catch(e => this.fileExists = false);
}
```

En `component.html` puedes añadir un `*ngIf` que en función del valor de `fileExists` renderice o no el div.

```html
<div [routerLink]="['/product/filtered']" [state]="{ id: famili.id}"
     class="columna card-1 img-fluid img-thumbnail shadow-sm p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded"
     [ngStyle]="{'background': ' url(../../../assets/' + famili.name + '.jpg) no-repeat 0 0','background-size': '100% 100%'}"
    *ngIf="fileExists"
>
   <div class="card-body-1 h4">
        {{famili.name | uppercase | translate }}
   </div>
</div>
```